# Trouble changing text of Android TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner

I'm doing a little testing of my spinner's `onItemSelected` function. What I'm doing I believe to be fairly simple, I have a text view in my activity with no starting string value (that is, the textview begins blank). I have two spinners, and I have my onItemSelected function set to retrieve the String values of the item selected and set this value to be the string value in the textview, for either spinner. Simple enough, but I can't get the textView to respond by displaying the item selected from either spinner, or worse yet for the onItemSelected function to be called properly. Here is the xml for my spinners and textview:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/iHaveSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/haveTextField"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/iWantSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iWantView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/resultView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iWantSpinner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"/>
```

and the activity's onItemSelected function:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View view, int pos, long id) {
    int ID = spinner.getId();
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView);
    switch(ID)
    {
        case (R.id.iHaveSpinner):
            String string1 = spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            result.setText(string1);
            break;
        case (R.id.iWantSpinner):
            String string2 = spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            result.setText(string2);
            break;
    }

}
```

Am I performing the `onItemSelected` function incorrectly? Are there any properties of a textView that aren't allowing me to edit the string value? It seems pretty straight forward, but looks like I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Simple fix, forgot to register the callback function for the spinners. I was missing the following two lines when initializing my spinners/populating spinner items:

```
iHaveSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
iWantSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

derp